# github.io has some strange behavior hosting images

Tags: python, html, github-pages

hi y'all I was wondering why the fimage under fib doesn't load in the page

https://krewn.github.io/ApophysisOutPuts/

The image clearly exists here

https://github.com/Krewn/ApophysisOutPuts/blob/gh-pages/Fib/adbg3.jpg

and the HTML obviously references it.

All the html was procedural written and I haven't had this problem before with any outputs so I don't think it's a typo...

Comment: I must have changed the folder name after I ran index.py and before I pushed... thanks @MarkoGrešak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing strange here. Just that paths are case sensitive, like with any *NIX file system. The path to image at [`index.html:2`](https://github.com/Krewn/ApophysisOutPuts/blob/gh-pages/index.html#L2) is using lowercase `fib` in path, where the actual folder name starts with an capital `Fib`.

Comment: How did the capitalization get changed? The code that made the html is here https://github.com/Krewn/ApophysisOutPuts/blob/master/Index.py

Comment: Looking at the page source, it's obviously not. If you're running this on windows, this might be an issue. IIRC the windows file system is case insensitive, so it doesn't care about capitalization of the `Fib` folder.